Domain of a function with two variables formed by the intersection of a circle and a line
I am analyzing the function
$$ f(x, y) = \sqrt{k - (x - x_0)^2 - (y - y_0)^2} + \frac{1}{x - x_1} $$
and I would like to discuss the properties of its domain with respect to the parameters $ x_0, y_0, x_1, $ and $ k $. Specifically, I want to know if the domain of this function is convex, closed, open, and connected.
The first term $ \sqrt{k - (x - x_0)^2 - (y - y_0)^2} $ suggests a circular region centered at $ (x_0, y_0) $ with a radius depending on $ k $. For this term to be defined, we need:
$$
   k - (x - x_0)^2 - (y - y_0)^2 \geq 0
   $$
This describes a disk (or circle) in the $ (x, y) $ plane.
The second term $ \frac{1}{x - x_1} $ is defined for all $ x \neq x_1 $, introducing a vertical asymptote.
If $ x_1 $ lies within the interval $[x_0 - \sqrt{k}, x_0 + \sqrt{k}]$, the domain is essentially the disk minus the vertical line $ x = x_1 $. In this case:
The domain is neither open nor closed.
The domain is not convex, as any segment or arc that crosses the line $ x = x_1 $ would include points along $ x = x_1 $, which are not in the domain.
What happens if $ x_1 $ lies outside the interval $[x_0 - \sqrt{k}, x_0 + \sqrt{k}]$? In this case, $ x = x_1 $ does not intersect the disk, so the entire disk would be in the domain. And what about the connectedness?

I think you might be overthinking matters in your head a bit. Assuming $x_0,y_0,x_1,k$ are given constants, your input space is probably meant to be taken as large as $\mathbb{R}^2$, minus any "problem points:" you've identified where those are:

Those $(x,y)$ such that you get a negative radicand
Those $(x,y)$ such that $x=x_1$

The first limits you to the disk of center $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $\sqrt k$, provided $k \ge 0$.
If the line $x=x_1$ is outside the disk, i.e. $|x| > \sqrt k$, then there are no problems and the domain is just the whole disk, because you are excluding that line from your domain. But if it's outside the disk, it is already excluded.
For instance, a particular example might be
$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 - x^2-y^2} + \frac{1}{x-2}
$$
The radical ensures the domain is the unit disk in the plane. The latter term forces $x \ne 2$ - but that doesn't matter, since $x=2$ is already outside the disk, so the domain is just the whole disk.
To see this more visually, here is a Desmos demo for your function. Observe how the graph of the function $f$ (green) as the plane $x=x_1$ (blue) passes through the disk part of the domain of the function (red).

Correspondingly, the domain has all the properties you expect of the closed disk: it is closed, convex, connected, etc.

So, when the line $ x = x_1  $ does not intersect the circle, I can say that the set is closed, connected, and convex, as you mentioned. But when the line intersects the circle at two points, then the set is neither closed nor open, not convex, and also not connected, right? I was also unsure about the connectedness—thanks!

Correct. The cut disk is neither closed nor open (notice how it's open at the cut but closed at the edges for instance), not convex (because lines crossing the cut will not lie entirely in the cut disk), and not connected.
